# the use of 'so' : "...neither said so to the other"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> "Neither of them much liked the idea of jumping into that pool, but neither said **so** to the other."

I don't understand the role of 'so' in that sentence. It seems that, without this conjunction, the sentence says the same.

Comment: Literally, *He said **so*** = *He said [something] **in such a manner***, but in practice we use it to mean *He said **that thing*** (where the *particular* thing he said has already been contextually identified). So it your context, *...neither of them said **that they didn't much like the idea of jumping into the pool** to the other*. Note that it's syntactically *required* to have some kind of "object" for the verb ***to say*** in the cited context (but it could be, for example, *...but neither said **this** to the other*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> ...but neither said to the other.

is not grammatically valid, the obvious response is "said what?". the word "so" serves to answer that question, it stands for the entire expression earlier in the sentence, that neither "much liked the idea of jumping into that pool".

The sentence could be rephrases with "that" in place of so, giving:

> Neither of them much liked the idea of jumping into that pool, but neither said that to the other.

Perhaps it is clearer to you that the word "that" is referring back to the previous statement. The meaning is the same, and "said so" or "say so" is a very common way of describing a statement matching a previously expressed sense. Some examples of this form would be:

> - I felt angry when John accused me of theft, but i didn't say so.
> - I think Sarah intends to marry Fred, but she hasn't said so.
> - If you want your boos to give you a raise, then you must say so.
> - He not only hinted that I should find a new apartment, he said so clearly.
> - If Mark meant that he disliked you, he would have said so.

In most of these, "so" could be replaced by "that", but the form with "so" is, in my experience, far more common.